# SQL Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have written a dynamic SQL Pivot Query that returns a Quantity per day, the number of columns returned are dynamic based on the number of days between the opening parameters. The issue I am having is that the Columns are not in DateOrder, I am guessing I need some form or Order By to fix this, does anyone have any ideas where I would need to put it in?

```
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    --declare and set variables
    DECLARE @v_Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@v_StartDate DATETIME = GETDATE() - 10
    ,@v_EndDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
    ,@v_Query VARCHAR(max)

--select results
SELECT @v_Columns = Coalesce(@v_Columns, '[') + convert(VARCHAR, cast(DateCreated AS DATE), 111) + '],['
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT cast(DateCreated AS DATE) AS DateCreated
    FROM TransactionOriginTracking
    ) tot
WHERE tot.DateCreated BETWEEN @v_StartDate
        AND @v_EndDate

SET @v_Columns = SUBSTRING(@v_Columns, 1, Len(@v_Columns) - 2)
SET @v_Query = 'select
    *
from
(
SELECT
    cast(Tracking.DateCreated as date) as [Date],
    th.TotalQuantity [Quantity]
FROM
    TransactionHeader th
    Inner JOin TransactionOriginTracking as Tracking on Tracking.TransactionHeaderId = th.Id
        and Tracking.WorkflowStageId = 9
    Inner Join CompanyDivision on CompanyDivision.Id = th.CompanyDivisionId
WHERE
    Tracking.DateCreated between ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @v_StartDate, 111) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @v_EndDate, 111) + '''
) as src
Pivot
(
SUM(src.Quantity)
For src.Date IN (' + @v_Columns + ')
) as PivotView'

EXEC (@v_Query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build up your column list, sort by date:

```
--select results
SELECT 
    @v_Columns = Coalesce(@v_Columns, '[') + convert(VARCHAR, cast(DateCreated AS DATE), 111) + '],['
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) AS DateCreated
     FROM 
         TransactionOriginTracking) tot
WHERE 
    tot.DateCreated BETWEEN @v_StartDate AND @v_EndDate
ORDER BY 
    tot.DateCreated
```